# How to "initialize" static variables in python derived classes?

Tags: python, class, inheritance

Sorry for the bad title, I haven't come up with a better description of my question.

Let's say I now have a base class A:

```
class A():
    def __init__(self, x,y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
    
    def add_p(self):
        print(self.p+self.x)
```

And now class B is the derived class:

```
class B(A):
    p = 10 # static variable
    def __init__(self,x,y,z):
        super(B,self).__init__(x,y)
        self.z = z
```

and now I can do:

```
b = B(1,2,3)
b.add_p() # output 11
```

But notice that class A **does not** have the member p, so if I do this will get error:

```
a = A(1,2)
A.add_p() # get error
```

What can I do improve this? Maybe make class A somehow like a virtual class?

This question is asked because I want to make a base class with all the methods, and make the derived classes. The difference between the base class and the derived class is that the derived class has some "static variables"(like p in the example, but different p in different derived classes). The above example can fit my need, but it seems a little not secure.

I appreciate any answer or help.

Comment: How about just making p = None class variable in A (don't think many people call them static btw)?

Comment: If the class variable is supposed to be created in child classes, then you shouldn't make instances of the base class in the first place. It should be virtual.

Comment: See [Abstract Base Class](https://docs.python.org/3/library/abc.html)

Comment: @AndrewAllaire What you mean is that we "initialize" p in A and let it's derived classes to "modify" by their own needs? Humm, I'll give it a try.

Comment: @Barmar I get the idea why you suggest me to do the abstract class instead of my current method. But if I have it right, I'll have to implement all the methods in the derived classes of the abstract class. That is not efficient because the "methods" of those derived classes are all the same, the difference is only the variable.

Comment: @AndrewAllaire Well, actually it doesn't work. Anyway, thank you for your help.